# Can't iterate over files in a directory, getting whole glob string as the file name without expansion

Tags: bash

I want to run a command on all files inside the directory, I have this:

```
for f in ~/*.yaml; do
    echo "$f"
    some_commands "$f"
done
```

But this gives:

```
File is not readable or does not exist: ~/*.yaml
```

Above happens in both cases when there are files in the directory or even when there isn't. I tried `shopt -s nullglob;` before the loop also but gives same results. Any way to achieve above?

Comment: The tilde should be expanded at least... Is this a [mre]? Maybe the actual glob is quoted (like  `for f in "~/*.yaml"`) or contained in a string (like `glob="~/*.yaml"; for f in $glob`), or you're not running this with Bash, or you accidentally enabled some shell options, though I don't think there is one to disable tilde expansion (vs `set -o noglob` to disable globbing). Try passing your script through [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and fix any problems it identifies.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue if I put `HOME='~'` before the snippet and swap in `ls` for `some_commands`: `ls: cannot access '~/*.yaml': No such file or directory`

Comment: Show your shebang and how you run your script.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
I tried removing `~` and replacing it with `/root`, still same.

Comment: The code you show in your question will never produce the output shown. At a minimum, the `echo` would produce some output (which will never be the sample output you have provided unless you have done the equivalent of `HOME='File is not readable or does not exist: ~'` somewhere before the lines shown).

Comment: Can you run `bash -x your-script` and paste output ?

Comment: `shopt` is not valid bash. If you did not get an error message, I would conclude that you are running zsh instead of bash. BTW, both shells - zsh and bash - let you decide what is supposed to happen when a glob does not have a valid expansion: Either the glob-expression is left unexpanded, or the glob-expression is removed from the line. You did not specify in your question, which policiy you would like to have, and it is not clear to me, what outcome you would like to see.

Comment: @user1934428 What version of `bash` are you using that does not understand `shopt` ?

Comment: @jhnc : Sorry, my bad.  You are right. But then, if if the OP does a `shopt -s nullglob` before the loop, then either the loop is skipped, or `f` gets the name of some yaml file. There is no way that `f` would still contain an asterisk with the code you provided. I would be interested in seeing a screenshot which proves his point. And, for the safe side, also a `echo $BASH_VERSINFO` before entering the loop, would make sense.

Comment: There is one case which could explain your observation (even with _nullglob_ turned on): If you have a file which has the name `*.yaml`, of course `f` would get this value.  To check for this case, do a `ls -l ~/'*'.yaml` before entering the loop. Also (picking up the idea behind the answer given by jhnc), replace the `echo` in the loop body by `xxd <<<$f`) and show us the outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlikely to be your problem, but a zero-width space or similar could give output that looks visually similar.

For example:

```bash
$ HOME=/wibble
$ echo ~/*.yaml
/wibble/*.yaml
$ echo ~​/*.yaml
~​/*.yaml
$ echo ~​/*.yaml | od -c
0000000   ~ 342 200 213   /   *   .   y   a   m   l  \n
0000014
#
```